# Login Form Directing user to multiple pages depending on the password

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, authentication

Could somebody please show me how I can set up my form below to log into different pages sharing the same name as the password. For instance Username: David     Password: Customer1

This will then direct the user to customer1.html.

and Username: Steve   Password: customer8, directs the user to customer8.html. I remember seeing a tutorial on this years ago using Javascript but I can not find anything now on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

```
<form name="password1">
<blockquote>
<blockquote>
  <p align="center">Client Login</p>
  <p><strong>Username: </strong>
    <input type="text" name="username2" size="15">
    <br>
    <strong>Password:&nbsp;</strong>
    <input type="password" name="password2" size="15">
  </p>
    <div align="center">
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitentry()" />
    </div>
</blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: needs to be done at server if you want any semblance of security

Comment: what you got in submitentry()

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments & as you have tagged PHP in your question, so I am providing you a server based solution.

**index.html**

```
<form name="password1" action="check.php" method="POST">
<blockquote>
  <p align="center">Client Login</p>
  <p><strong>Username: </strong>
  <input type="text" name="username2" size="15">
  <br>
  <strong>Password:&nbsp;</strong>
<input type="password" name="password2" size="15">
</p>
<div align="center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</blockquote>
</form>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['password2'])){
$password = stripslashes($_POST['password2']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);

// You may verify whether the username & password entered matches with database or not

$address = "$password".".html";
header("location: $address");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your check.php

SELECT your username & password for checking.

Use IF ELSE to make it work.

```
if($password = 'customer1')
{
  header("location: customer1.html");
  exit;
}
.
. 
.
else if($password = 'customer8')
{
  header("location: customer8.html");
  exit;
}
```